# Lightweight Mac application to store and lookup small pieces of text quickly

Tags: osx, note-taking, text-search

I am looking for a lightweight Mac application to create and lookup short texts like e.g. commands on the fly. Maybe a menu bar application. Extensive keyboard support would be great. 
I used [nvALT](http://brettterpstra.com/projects/nvalt/), but a regular window needs to be opened. Applications like Evernote are overkill. [Dash](http://kapeli.com/dash) has a cheat sheet feature, but it needs some effort to implement individual entries.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried Google Keep? Could that be an alternative for you?

Comment: This Question needs more specifics. For example, how does the bundled [Notes.app](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notes_%28application%29) not suffice?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you look into a combination of [Quicksilver](http://qsapp.com) (or Alfred) and Notational Velocity (or [Simplenote](http://www.simplenote.com)). Very simple, and very efficient. Probably nvAlt itself can cooperate with one of these two launchbars (Quicksilver / Alfred), in which case you won't even have to change your note taking software).

Comment: I can search nvAlt using LaunchBar, but this does not help much.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more so we can help? What aspect of the current interface is not satisfying? For instance if LaunchBar could preview the doc, would that be of any help (so you won't have to open any window)?

Answer (score 0):

Low-octane solution:

Spotlight shows quick view of the file found, so for each word you could create some text file, named `(some_prefix)_(word).txt`, for example `zz_stack.txt`. Then just call spotlight from the keyboard, type `zz_stack` and see your result.

Answer (score -1):

## Apple Notes

The [Apple Notes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notes_%28application%29) app comes bundled with your Mac, free of charge.

You can create one note or many. Quick to launch. Automatically syncs across Macs and iOS devices. Easily searchable within the app or across your Mac via Spotlight.

Comment: Dear Down-Voter, please leave a criticism along with your vote.